# How to match parallel columns text after section title?

Tags: parbox, paracol

I'd like to match the text first line between two columns at the same vertical level after their respective section titles.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \section*{\centering Section Title}
        \parbox[t]{\columnwidth}{
            \vspace{\baselineskip}
            \lipsum[2]
        }
        \switchcolumn
        \section*{\centering CAPITALIZED SECTION TITLE}
        \parbox[t]{\columnwidth}{
            \lipsum[4]
        }
    \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that both section have the same number of lines:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \section*{\centering Section Title\\~}
        \parbox[t]{\columnwidth}{
            \lipsum[2]
        }
        \switchcolumn
        \section*{\centering CAPITALIZED SECTION TITLE}
        \parbox[t]{\columnwidth}{
            \lipsum[4]
        }
    \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A great answer providing a simple solution. (you just beat me to it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could switch columns after the `\section`s, using `\switchcolumn*` to align the columns.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \section*{\centering Section Title}
      \switchcolumn
        \section*{\centering CAPITALIZED SECTION TITLE}
      \switchcolumn*
        \lipsum[2]
      \switchcolumn
        \lipsum[4]
    \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```